# Javascript append - append multiple elements with values from array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append elements with multiple values from my array, but i am doing something wrong. This is my code:

```
for(var i=0; i < pricesArray.length; i++) {
      var ulList = document.getElementById('season-prices');

      ulList.append(`
        <div class="flex"> <input type="checkbox"></input> <span>` + pricesArray[i].start_date `</span> <span>` + pricesArray[i].end_date `</span> 
        <span>` + pricesArray[i].currency `</span> <span>` + pricesArray[i].price `</span>  </div>
      `)
    }
```

The error I get is:

> pricesArray[i].start_date is not a function

Is there another way, or a better way to do this? I used to do something like this in jQuery but cannot remember where and how exactly..

Comment: please show what pricesArray contains

Comment: @YoukouleleY It contains these properties I wrote in the code, start_date, end_date..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing '**+**' after pricesArray[i].start_date. also after every property. you need to put plus symbol in front and back.

```
for(var i=0; i < pricesArray.length; i++) {
          var ulList = document.getElementById('season-prices');

          ulList.append(`
            <div class="flex"> <input type="checkbox"></input> <span>` + pricesArray[i].start_date + `</span> <span>` + pricesArray[i].end_date + `</span> 
            <span>` + pricesArray[i].currency +`</span> <span>` + pricesArray[i].price + `</span>  </div>
          `)
        }
```

Comment: To clarify for everybody: before the back-tick without an operator, a [tag function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) was expected.

Comment: Ah, jesus... but there is another issue now, it is appending these elements as string, not as HTML elements, what should I change for that?

Comment: try to use : ulList.innerHTML += {your string}